# How to run multiple python scripts with inputs in bash

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu

I tried

```
for j in {1..2}; do
    python screener_beta1.py&
done
```

But, the screener_beta1 actually takes 3 user inputs. How can I specifiy the inputs in each python script?

Comment: don't create a loop. Pass the required arguments in multiple calls

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "inputs"?

Comment: @melpomene is a python script, like input("Type your name: )

Comment: Remove the ampersand and have each of the 3 scripts "block" and run in the foreground. You can't send user input (from the keyboard) to backgrounded procs which is what you get when you use the `&`.

Comment: @smassey I used import sys. Then assess the variable using sys.argv[1]. That's OK now.